# Lipschitz constant for a second order nonlinear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions

I'm trying to calculate the Lipschitz constant for a second order nonlinear differential equation:

$$y'' + y' + y^n = 0, \; y(0)=0, \; y'(0)= 0 \text{ and } n>1$$

Should I solve for $y(x)$ and differentiate the solution to find a bound ($L$, Lipschitz constant) on $\vert f'(x) \vert$? Or does it mean that I have to differentiate $f(x)= y'' + y' + y^n$? I would like some tips to proceed as this is my first calculation of this kind. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To apply the formalism you use the Lipschitz constant for, you first need to transform the ODE into a first order system,
\begin{align}
y'&=v\\
v'&=-v-y^n.
\end{align}
Next we know that non-linear polynomials are never globally Lipschitz, you only get a local Lipschitz constant on a set like $|y|<R$. Then
\begin{align}
\|F(y_2,v_2)-F(y_1,v_1)\|_{\max}&=\max(|v_2-v_1|,|v_2-v_1+y_2^n-y_1^n|)\\
&\le |v_2-v_1|+nR^{n-1}|y_2-y_1|\\
&\le (1+nR^{n-1})\|(y_2,v_2)-(y_1,v_1)\|_{\max}
\end{align}
This is sufficient to prove uniqueness, but only local existence. No claim on the maximal domain follows from this bound.

Comment: Thank you! I will still need some time to assimilate all the information but this is really helpfull. Happy hollydays LutzL!

Comment: After a while, I have been able to prove that $$|y_2^n -y_1^n| \simeq nR^{n-1}|y_2 - y_1| $$ where R is the possible interval [-R,R] but I'm not sure how to get rid off $|v_2 - v_1|$ and combine it to get $|(y_2,v_2) - (y_1,v_1)|_{max}$. What book would you recommend in this matter? Again, thanks in advance.

Comment: I know that Lipschitz constant is $(1+nR^{n-1})$, however I'm not sure how would it affect if the second equation of the system was $v' = -2v - y^n$, for instance.

Comment: Then you get $(2+nR^{n-1})$ as Lipschitz constant. By playing with the norm, scaling one of the components, one can reduce the Lipschitz constant somewhat, distribute it over the equations.

Comment: This is becoming a master class, but I have got one more question. To be a contraction mapping it is required L< 1, something that in this case we have not. Fixed point theorem is not allowed, however starting from a close enough solution it converges. From your experience, have you seen this happening sometimes? Also, when you told that it is allowed to have a L constant on a set $|y|< R$ but I get on $|x|< R$, is there something that I'm missing? Thank you, I appreciate your help because this is much like art to me.

Comment: In the totally local version of Picard-Lindelöf you have to use, there are indeed restrictions on both $x$ and $y$, usually formulated as $|x-x_0|<T$ and $\|y-y_0\|<R$ or any combination of variable names. For the existence theorem, the existence of any Lipschitz constant is sufficient, the $x$ region gets restricted so that the contraction constant for the BFS in the proof can be chosen as $1/2$.

Comment: In contraction constant for the BFS, what does BFS stand for? Choosing a constant close to one (L<1) would give me the maximal domain?

Comment: Sorry, German acronym, "Banachscher Fixpunktsatz". And no, while there are situations where more global versions of the existence theorem can be applied, usually one needs to compose the maximal solution from many patches of local solutions.

Comment: Thank you, very helpfull. I see that there is a Lozinsky theorem that might extend this domain a bit or even to the full domain. This is a never ending process of learning, thank you!